# mine a block chain without transaction

Tags: private-blockchain

I created a private block with custom genesis.json with command `geth --datadir {path} init {pathToGenesis}`. Then I create two new accounts, there is only two account in this block chain. I start mining by command `miner.start(2)`.
logs are shown below:

```
INFO [01-02|07:55:09]  mined potential block  number=4138 hash=f2f1b9…35ad00
INFO [01-02|07:55:09] Commit new mining work number=4139 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=243.38µs
INFO [01-02|07:55:12] Successfully sealed new block
```

Then I checked my `eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])` and found there are a lot of ether in the account.

In my understanding, account finds pending transactions, provides PoW, seals new transactions in a new block and finally get gas as reward. But, how can the account get ethers when there is not even a single transaction at all.

My question is:
Why I can mine ethers even if there is no transaction in block chain?
What did I seal in the new block?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The miner still gets block reward even when there is no transaction. See section "Mining Rewards" of [this page](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mining) from Ethereum wiki. Basically, there are two other non transaction fee types of reward:

- static block reward
- Uncle inclusion reward.